# when two computer communicating(sending and receiving) with each other through the twisted cable, then the current in the wire is ac or dc?

Tags: current, ac, dc

cables that connect the two computer system carry ca current signal or dc current signal?

when two computer communicating(sending and receiving) with each other through the twisted cable, then the current in the wire is ac or dc?

Comment: DC doesn't carry information, so there has to be some AC component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the sort of signalling you are using, and on your definition of AC.

For true RS-232 serial communications, a "1" bit is represented by a negative voltage, and a "0" is represented by a positive voltage, so you might call that AC - but it is a series of pulses, and stays negative when the line is idle (no characters being transmitted).

For many other serial protocols, the signal does not change polarity, but is still a series of pulses.  Whether you consider this AC with a DC offset or pulsing DC is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Think about morse code and two operators sat miles apart. If the sender just pressed his morse send key and held it there continuously, the guy at the other end would receive a single ping and nothing else. How would the receiver guy know that he was being told a train was coming down the line?

This applies whether it’s twisted pair cables or old telegraphy wiring; to send information requires encoding and sophistication that cannot be achieved with pure DC.

Sophistication requires altering the coded symbols sent down the line so that complex meaning can be imparted. The word alternating can mean a continual repeat of the same symbol (as in AC power transmission) and, this imparts no long term information but, generally, we say the information transmitted requires alternating current. Whether this is superimposed on some DC level is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified, it's switched DC. The communication is encoded into bits that are represented by discreet voltage levels - low and high, at its simplest 0 and 5 volts.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. E.g. for ethernet, it's AC. That is by design because AC enables you to use isolation transformers and common-mode chokes, which is great for longer distances.